# Different between ajax & json

Tags: ajax

i want to know about what is the different between **Ajax** and **Json**.  can u please tell me about them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not search on google or wikipedia.

Take a look at:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
```

**Copyed** :

AJAX stands for Asynchronous Javascript and XML, which is a mechanism used to launch asynchronous HTTP requests to a server using JavaScript. Don't let the name fool you; there's no restriction on you only retrieving JavaScript or XML from this technique. You can quite happily return other data formats as well (HTML, plain text and JSON, to list a few).

JSON is just one of these formats. It's a data interchange format, where-as AJAX is a technique to communicate with a server after the initate page load has completed.

To answer your question on whether you need to specify the dataType; jQuery will best guess the response format (be it HTML or JSON etc), so you're usually fine to omit it

Comment: I understood about ajax. but cant understood Jason can u please elaborate in your language or what is in your mind about Jason.